# Python - how to get table id

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

The HTML is shown as below. How can i get the id="table_1880381"?

```html
<div class="match" id="table_1880381"><div class="m_info"><div class="game" style="background-color:#669900;"><a href="http://info.win007.com/cn/subleague.aspx?sclassid=140" target="_blank">墨西聯</a><br/><span id="mt_1880381">7-31 02:30</span> </div><div class="time" id="time_1880381"><font color="red">完</font></div><div class="home" id="home_1880381"><div class="teamInfo"><div class="match" id="table_1851236"><div class="m_info"><div class="game" style="background-color:#64ba1e;"><a href="http://info.win007.com/cn/subleague.aspx?sclassid=772" target="_blank">烏茲超</a><br><span id="mt_1851236">8-18 20:00</span> </div><div class="time" id="time_1851236"><font color="red">完</font></div><div class="home" id="home_1851236"><div class="teamInfo"> <a href="javascript:Panlu(1851236)"><b>克孜勒庫姆</b></a>(中)[14]</div>
```

```
    container3 = soup.findAll("div", {"match": "id"})
    print(container3)
```

When i run the above code, the result should be []. As i want to the result should be 1880381
Anyone mistake on the code?

Comment: [<div class="match" id="table_1880381"><div class="m_info"><div class="game" style="background-color:#669900;"><a href="http://info.win007.com/cn/subleague.aspx?sclassid=140" target="_blank">墨西聯</a><br/><span id="mt_1880381">7-31 02:30</span> </div><div class="time" id="time_1880381"><font color="red">完</font></div><div class="home" id="home_1880381"><div class="teamInfo">

Comment: Please edit your question and, first, add the html to it (not in a comment) and, second, show what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: i don't know why i can't add it via html. And the expected output 1880381

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is confusing, but there are a number of ways to get to where you want to go.

Try something like:

```
soup.select_one('div.home').attrs['id'].split('_')[1]
```

or

```
soup.select_one('div.time').attrs['id'].split('_')[1]
```

Output, in either case:

```
'1880381'
```

For your modified html:

```
for item in soup.select('div.home'):
    print(item['id'].split('_')[1])
```

Output:

```
1880381
1851236
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. The answer is great. if there have many id is under 1880381, how can i get all the id?

Comment: @Alau0828 - I'm not sure what you mean. Can you edit your question with an example?

Comment: Thanks Jack. I changed the question which added the html with 2 id. There have 2 id (1880381, 1851236)...i expect result should be '1880381', '1851236'